# Pointer to existing array instead of copy

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a Packet struct and it contains some header info and a malloc'ed byte array. When I want to write that packet out, I malloc a new byte array, insert the header info, and then memcpy the structs payload byte array into the new buffer. Could I make a byte array without creating a copy? This is going to live on an Arduino with 2K of RAM and I want to make every byte count. I was also thinking of leaving the original byte array intact, and just making pointers to the values in the byte array that correlate to the fields.

Here's my current code:

```
// .h
typedef struct BLEPacket {
    uint8_t  protocol;
    uint8_t  meta;
    uint16_t length;
    uint16_t checksum;
    const uint8_t* payload;
} BLEPacket;


//.c
uint8_t* bytesFromBLEPacket(BLEPacket packet){
    uint8_t *outBuffer = malloc(packet.length);
    outBuffer[0] = packet.protocol;
    outBuffer[1] = packet.meta;
    outBuffer[2] = highOrderByte(packet.length);
    outBuffer[3] = lowOrderByte(packet.length);
    outBuffer[4] = highOrderByte(packet.checksum);
    outBuffer[5] = lowOrderByte(packet.checksum);

    if (packet.payload != NULL){
        memcpy(outBuffer+PACKET_HEADER_SIZE, packet.payload, packet.length - PACKET_HEADER_SIZE);
    }
    return outBuffer;
}
```

Edits:
I don't have a great C background, so I'm not entirely sure if/how I can just directly access the memory in that way. Can I do something like `byte[0] = packet.payload - PACKET_HEADER_SIZE`?

```
// ios client.m
-(void)sendMessage:(NSString*)message {
    NSData *data = [message dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    BLEPacket packet = BLEPacketCompose(MetaMessage, data.bytes, data.length);
    [self writePacket:packet];
}

-(void)writePacket:(BLEPacket)packet {
    uint8_t bytes[packet.length];
    bytesFromBLEPacket(packet,bytes); // updated with non-malloc version
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:packet.length];
    [self write:data]; // CoreBluetooth update characteristic value
}

// arduino.ino - a simple echo for now. I'm planning on including the same BLEPacket.h/.c file
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200); 
}

void loop() {
    if(Serial.available()) {
        Serial.write(Serial.read());  //echo, writes one byte at a time, in order
    }
}
```

I also need the packet as a byte array for checksum-ing it. It's also occurring to me now that I could just hardcode in checksumming/byte by byte writing for a packets header, than iterate over the payload. But still, for the sake of learning, how can I access the fields of a struct as a byte array without dumping them into another array?

Comment: can't you simply free the memory on `BLEPacket` after the `memcpy`?

Comment: Then at some point I'd need `2*sizeOf(BLEPacket)`

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? if you want to return just the bytes then just return the bytes, why create a new buffer and return it? You can check if it's good then just return packet.payload itself, or packet.payload + N, where N is your offset

Comment: There's no need to make a copy, you can simply take the address of the packet, i.e. `&packet`. For a more complete answer, you need to show us what you do with `outBuffer` after calling that function.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do NOT use malloc/free from C and new/delete from C++ on small RTOSes and baremetal embedded systems.  [Big no-no!](http://mil-embedded.com/articles/justifiably-apis-militaryaerospace-embedded-code/)

Second of all, yes, you can pass in a pointer to a buffer that is statically defined outside your function.  It will look something like this:

```
uint8_t bytesFromBLEPacket(BLEPacket packet, uint8_t* outBuffer, uint16_t outBufferSize) {

    // Do some basic sanity checking on the buffer size that was passed in
    if ( outBufferSize < 6 ) {
        // buffer is too small, return some error
        return 1;
    }

    if ( outBuffer == NULL ) {
        // buffer not allocated, return some error
        return 2;
    }

    outBuffer[0] = packet.protocol;
    outBuffer[1] = packet.meta;
    outBuffer[2] = highOrderByte(packet.length);
    outBuffer[3] = lowOrderByte(packet.length);
    outBuffer[4] = highOrderByte(packet.checksum);
    outBuffer[5] = lowOrderByte(packet.checksum);

    if (packet.payload != NULL){
        memcpy(outBuffer+PACKET_HEADER_SIZE, packet.payload, packet.length - PACKET_HEADER_SIZE);
    }

    return 0;
}

// You can call your new function like so:
#define BUFF_SIZE 10

uint8_t buffer[BUFF_SIZE] = {0};
uint16_t bufferSize = BUFF_SIZE;
int status = bytesFromBLEPacket( packet, buffer, bufferSize );
```